# split a string array to a jagged object array

Tags: c#, arrays, function, jagged-arrays

I want to make a string array with values of names and some numbers(which are strings)
i want to pass them into a function that will take the array and then split them into an object jagged array (1 array of strings and 1 array of ints)
the array is:

```
string[] str= { "toto", "the", "moto", "my", "friend","12","13","14","99","88"};
```

and the function looks like this:

```
public object[][] bloop (string[] bstr)
{

}
```

whats next?

Comment: Next step: you show us what you've tried.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DHPRuDTu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static object[][] bloop(string[] bstr)
    {
        object[][] result = new object[2][] { new object[bstr.Length], new object[bstr.Length] };
        int sFlag = 0, iFlag = 0, val;            
        foreach (string str in bstr)
            if (int.TryParse(str, out val))
                result[1][iFlag++] = val;
            else
                result[0][sFlag++] = str;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: It seems that you've allocated *too many items* with `new object[bstr.Length]`; that's why tail items of `bloop` will be `null`s

Comment: Yes, you are right, we can't predict how many strings/integers will be there, we can this avoid by using Generic collections/List and Auto Increment able arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Your scenario looks like bad design that can cause errors and performance issues. The better way is to change code for using generic `List<>` or something like that. But in your current problem you can use below code:

```
public object[][] bloop (string[] bstr)
{
    var numbers = new List<int>();
    var strings = new List<string>();
    var result = new object[2][];

    foreach(var str in bstr)
    {
        int number = 0;
        if(int.TryParse(str, out number))
        {
            numbers.Add(number);
        }
        else
        {
            strings.Add(str);
        }
    }

    result[0] = strings.ToArray();
    result[1] = numbers.ToArray();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that your requirement sounds odd and should be solved with a different approach. However, this will do what you want:

```
public T[][] Bloop<T>(T[] items)
{
    if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
    if (items.Length == 1) return new T[][] { items, new T[] { } };

    int firstLength = (int) Math.Ceiling((double)items.Length / 2);
    T[] firstPart = new T[firstLength];
    Array.Copy(items, 0, firstPart, 0, firstLength);
    int secondLength = (int)Math.Floor((double)items.Length / 2);
    T[] secondPart = new T[secondLength];
    Array.Copy(items, firstLength, secondPart, 0, secondLength);
    return new T[][] { firstPart, secondPart };
}
```

Your sample:

```
string[] str= { "toto", "the", "moto", "my", "friend","12","13","14","99","88"};
string[][] result = Bloop(str);
```

If you need the second array as `int[]` you could use following:

```
int[] ints = Array.ConvertAll(result[1], int.Parse);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Linq* solution.

You have *two groups*: first one has items that can be parsed to `int` and the second group contains all the others, so `GroupBy` looks quite naturally:

```
public Object[][] bloop(string[] bstr) {
  if (null == bstr)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("bstr");

  int v;

  return bstr
    .GroupBy(x => int.TryParse(x, out v))
    .OrderBy(chunk => chunk.Key) // let strings be the first
    .Select(chunk => chunk.ToArray())
    .ToArray();
}
```

Test:

```
string[] str = { "toto", "the", "moto", "my", "friend", "12", "13", "14", "99", "88" };

// toto, the, moto, my, friend
// 12, 13, 14, 99, 88
Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
   bloop(str).Select(x => String.Join(", ", x))));
```